# How do I check whether I have the latest Far Cry patch on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, far-cry-3

I have the somewhat infamous rock/camera glitch and it was [supposedly patched in the 1.04 update](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632849-far-cry-3/65338735), but I'm never prompted to download a patch (either through the usual Xbox patch system or Ubisoft's in-game system) and I don't know whether it was automatically installed. If it was, I'm not receiving the benefits. How can I determine whether I have the latest update, and, if related, what do I need to do to get it? Is there a place where I can check the current version number?

To clarify, I've cleared my cache and the game doesn't prompt me for an official Xbox patch, unlike most other games.

Comment: If you're signed into Xbox Live, I believe you're required to take a patch or be logged out for the game session if you refuse.  I don't think there's any way to manually patch a game, but there might be subtle variations from game to game on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with agent86's comment, and his related answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53950/21619).  I've been playing on XBL for years, and you can not play a game and connect to Live if you do not have the most current patch.  It is possible to see these patches on your storage device, but it is hard to determine the version other than by date.  If you want to check that out, go to **Settings** > **System** > **Storage** > ***Select drive you use for this game*** > **Games and Apps** > ***Game Name*** (Far Cry 3 in this case).  You should see a file called "Title update" if the game has been patched - and selecting that file should show you the date and size, which could be used to determine which version you are running.

[image: Title Update]

Comment: Nice work! I've never seen the "Title Update" as an item in the Storage list before—is this a new standard or am I late to the game? The trick was deleting this file, which didn't clear with the cache. Thank you

Comment: @Sean I think title updates only started appearing in your used space with the last dashboard update or so, before they were taking up space but you couldn't tell how much.